# Сделать так, чтобы функция не запускалась много раз

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется 2 разные таблицы в 2 вкладках(Табы бутстрап).
Есть 1 кнопка под этими двумя таблицами с классом .add_stroke. При нажатии на неё она добавляет строку в конец таблицы на той вкладке на которой она была нажата. Реализовал это путём создания двух функций. При переходе по вкладке т.е. нажатии на ссылку в меню запускается определённая функция.
Проблема в том что при первом запуске функции добавляется одна строка, а если нажать ещё раз на ссылку вкладки функция запускается ещё раз и строк добавляется уже по 2. И так +1 при каждом запуске функции. Как сделать чтобы функция прерывалась при запуске другой функции или чтобы эта же функция не запускалась много раз.

**Создаю функции:**

```
function armaturaJs() {
  $('.add_stroke').click(function() {
    newStroke = "<tr><td>test</td></tr>";
    $(newStroke).insertBefore('div#home .send_button_tr');
  });
}

function rectPipeJs() {
  $('.add_stroke').click(function() {
    newStroke = "<tr><td>test</td></tr>";
    $(newStroke).insertBefore('div#profile .send_button_tr');
  });
}
```

**Запуск функций:**

```
  $('a#home-tab').click(function() {
    armaturaJs();
  });
  $('a#profile-tab').click(function() {
    rectPipeJs();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при вызове функций добавляется еще один обработчик всем существующим элементам с классом `add_stroke`.

Простым решением может стать сброс уже навешанных обработчиков с помощью метода [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), например так:

```
$('.add_stroke').off().click(function() {
    newStroke = "<tr><td>test</td></tr>";
    $(newStroke).insertBefore('div#profile .send_button_tr');
});
```

и аналогично в другой функции.

Comment: Другим простым решением является более точная выборка элемента, и навешивание обработчика ровно 1 раз.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на сколько я понял, элемент тот же самый, просто на разных табах ему разные обработчики добавляются, поэтому более точная выборка тут не совсем пройдет

Comment: Написано же: *"с одинаковым классом .add_stroke"*. Про одну и ту же кнопку будет не по-русски говорить, что у нее *одинаковый* класс...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нужен [mcve] от автора, иначе мы сейчас напридумываем что там может быть и как его понять

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо не правильно выразился. Кнопка одна, табов много.